# Custom Tensorflow optimizer for noisy non-differentiable loss function

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, loss-function

I have build a model using the low-level tensorflow API that has only a couple of variables (about 10) that I want to optimize. Therefore I want to implement a custom loss function that produces noisy loss values (kind of like a simulation based optimization approach).

Usually I would a derivative free optimizer like the SPSA optimizer.

*Is there a way to implement a loss function that is not differentiable and an optimizer like SPSA with the low-level tensorflow API?*

PS: One might ask why use tensorflow for this? This is because I want to use tensorflow for convenient saving of the model and tensorboard for convenient and comprehensive visualization. Also I want to be able to switch and compare different models in a standardized framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SPSA will work with non-differentiable functions also.
For SPSA implementation: https://github.com/fraunhofer-iais/tensorflow_spsa